# $location.path without reload the view angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Here is my routing configuration:

```js
$routeProvider.
  when('/prods/', {
    templateUrl: function (urlAttr) {
      return '/views/prods.html';
    }
  }).
  when('/prods/:id', {
    reloadOnSearch: false
  })
```

In 'prod' view I have a table with all the products.

Now, I want that when the user will click on a row, to display the product details.
Also, I want to "redirect" the user to new url `/prods/{{prod_id}}`. For this I using: `$location.path` In the way:

```js
$scope.$apply(function () {
  $location.path('/prods/' + prod_id);
});
```

My problem is that when the URL change, the view deleted.
If I add `templateUrl` property to the prod page routing, the view refreshed. 
I want that when I change the URL, nothing will happens.

Comment: Why can't you just change the `search` portion of the hash URL when someone clicks on a product? e.g. `$location.search({productId: product.id});`. What you are currently describing does not seem very RESTful to me.

Comment: Because I want that the URL will be built hierarchy. This simple and legitimate.